# File contents not deleted in linux centos

Tags: bash, centos

I have the program running using this command

`command 2> sample.txt`

now that file is growing continuously and command will exit in 5-6 days and i beleive that file size won't go in GB

I tried this

`echo "" > sample.txt` but thats not making any differnce to it and filesize is growing.

i was thinking of setting up cron job after 1 hour to empty its contents

How can i empty the contents of file

Comment: Why store the contents in file at all if you are going to empty it every hour?

Comment: i just want to know the progress of the command by using tail to see if it has any error or running properly

Comment: Can't you `rm sample.txt && touch $_`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command, this will write the console output to a file. (Your console will also get the messages printed).

```
command | tee -a file.log
```

and you can empty the contents by

```
> file.log
```